# Delegate returns prematurely

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

I have a delegate that returns a DataTable. The problem is that in GetPendingThings (see below) the method returns in the middle of the foreach loop. Let's say I have a collection of 50 object in myThingsToAddToTable to add as rows to the data table; the foreach loop will iterate 30, 31, sometimes 32 times and then jump to the return statement, leaving my data table incomplete.

```
private delegate DataTable ExecuteQueryDelegate();
private ExecuteQueryDelegate MyThingsDelegate;

private void LoadMyThings(){
  MyThingsDelegate = new ExecuteQueryDelegate(GetPendingThings);
  MyThingsDelegate.BeginInvoke(this.MyThingsReceivedCallback, null);
}

private void MyThingsReceivedCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
  DataTable dt = MyThingsDelegate.EndInvoke(ar);
  //do stuff with dt
}

private DataTable GetPendingThings() {
  DataTable dt = CreateMyThingsDataTable();
  var myThingsToAddToTable = //linq query

  foreach (var a in myThingsToAddToTable){
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); 
    CreateMyThingsDataRow(dr, a.x, a.y, a.z);
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
  }
  return dt;
}
```

Comment: What you describe is not possible; more likely, the query stored in `myThingsToAddToTable` represents fewer elements than you think it does.  (Call `.Count()` on it to verify.)

Comment: Hi cdhowie, I have already tried that. There is a discrepancy, so it's definitely possible.

Comment: No, it's not possible unless there is an exception being thrown within the loop.  You do not have a return statement, so returning from within the loop is *not possible*.  It may be possible that the data the query is using changes while the loop is executing, though, causing you to enumerate fewer elements than you had when you started.

Comment: You're absolutely right. There are uncaught exceptions being thrown left and right in the CreateMyThingsDataRow method, causing it to break out of the loop early. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if one of the method calls inside the loop throws an exception, which would cause the method to not return any value at all, but rather terminate early and propagate the exception to the caller (in this case, the exception would show up when you call `EndInvoke()`).

It's remotely possible that the data you are querying is changing mid-loop, but that *should* trigger an `InvalidOperationException` due to modification during enumeration.